# missing values in contingency tables

Tags: r

I am trying to create a mosaic plot with a data frame converted into a contingency table. The problem is that the table contains many NA values, and the message that is shown when I try to build the mosaic plot is "missing values in contingency table". How can I overcome the problem of NAs? I have tried to ignore them by typing >mytable[rowSums(is.na(mytable))==0, ] but it doesn´t work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that is just a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to simply remove all rows that contain any NAs in them:

```
mytable <- mytable[complete.cases(mytable), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

the hyperdirichlet package includes a vignette that analyses this problem using four or five different techniques.  HTH!